# адаптер для RecyclerView: список карт

Tags: android, recyclerview, recyclerview.adapter

Коллеги.
необходимо список карт показывать в таком виде:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

подозреваю, что нужен специальный адаптер.

идея была подсмотрена в приложении Сбербанк, нужная реализация есть так же в приложении Кошелёк

Comment: а вы что-то сделали в этом направлении кроме публикации вопроса?)

Comment: Открою великую тайну - для `RecyclerView` всегда нужен *специальный адаптер*, так что ваши *подозрения* - обоснованы. Дерзайте.

Comment: Из того что может вызвать трудности у новичка - вижу только правый вариант расположения карт, но это решается будь у вас класс адаптера или макет карточки.

Comment: на github есть готовые решения. например [такой LayoutManager](https://github.com/amyu/StackCardLayoutManager). можете взять готовый или посмотреть как устроен и сделать свой. другие [варианты реализации](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=recyclerview+stack+card&type=)

Comment: [pavlofff](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/177345/pavlofff), спасибо, буду работать в этом направлении

Answer (score 0):

Готовое решение вы вряд ли найдете. Вам нужно написать свой LayoutManager. Штука не плевая, но ничего экстраординарного в ней нет. Если потратите достаточно времени - получите то, что хотите. Для примера оставлю [ссылочку](https://habr.com/ru/company/true_engineering/blog/267497/), чтоб было с чего начать

Comment: спасибо за ссыль, буду изучать тему, мне теперь надо этот StackCardLayoutManager привязать SwipeRefreshLayout и сделать Swipe to Refresh

Comment: @SuperVital В этом нет нужды, просто положите recyclerView в SwipeRefreshLayout, они вполне себе дружат. Менеджер должен только располагать вьюшки на местах, остальное не его забота

Comment: правда? хорошо, Дмитрий, у меня, с первого раза, не заработало, посмотрю что не так, буду пробывать их подружить...